# Проверить input value и присвоить class

Tags: javascript, form, input, submit

Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста элементарщину:

1. Есть форма:

```html
<form class="form" id="f_questions" onsubmit="return checkForm_questions(this)">
```

2. Есть инпуты (их несколько, но вот 1, в качестве примера):

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name_questions" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя">
```

3. Есть псевдо-кнопка сабмита:

```html
<input class="btn1" type="submit" value="Получить ответ">
```

4. Надо: проверить на пустоту все инпуты и если они не пустые, то присвоить кнопке класс (class="btn-answer").

(зы, прошу прощения, если флуд) =)

Comment: а что значит input не пустой в вашем понимании? Если value ничего не записано?

Comment: Да, если value не пустой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#f_questions').focusout(function(){
  var empty = true;
  $(this).find('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      empty = true;
      return false;
    }
    empty = false;
  });
  
  if(!empty) {
    $('.btn1').addClass('btn-answer')
  } else {
    $('.btn1').removeClass('btn-answer')
  }
});
```

```css
.btn-answer {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" id="f_questions" onsubmit="return checkForm_questions(this)">
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name_questions1" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя">
  <input type="text" name="name2" id="name_questions2" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя">
  <input type="text" name="name3" id="name_questions3" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя">
  <input type="text" name="name4" id="name_questions4" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя">
  <input class="btn1" type="submit" value="Получить ответ">
</form>
```

Comment: В вашем способе работает действие, которое повешено на сабмит формы. В остальных случаях почему-то нет)

Answer (score 1):

Вот мое решение(нам не нужно проверять пустой `value` или нет, а просто сразу все берем пустые и их изменяем):

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[value=""]');
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].className = 'btn-answer';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function checkForm_questions(form){
    let i = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

    if([].every.call(i, (i) => {
       return !!i.value;
    })) form.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').className = "btn-answer";

    return false;
}
```